Why are my obj objects are turning white?
I was importing a obj file from Roblox studio and most of the colors of the obj that i imported turned white.but that wasnt their color so that was wierd so can anybody help me?


hello maybe there's an option about materials when you import and obj? Please select an object and show a screenshot of the Shader Editor window
